# アプリ内で撮影した動画を、フォトライブラリではなくアプリ内で保存する方法

Tags: swift, database, coredata, 動画

現在Swiftを使いiOSアプリの開発中で、勉強を開始して3ヶ月ほどの初心者です。
・カメラ機能を使い動画を撮影
・動画一覧ページで撮影日時と動画の説明を表示
・撮影した動画の再生、編集
主にこの３つができるアプリを作成しています。

カメラ機能を使いフォトライブラリに動画を保存するところまではたどり着いたのですが、
フォトライブラリではなくアプリ内に動画を保存したく、その方法に迷っております。
自分なりに調べたところ、下記２つの方法が考えられるかと思ったのですが

１.CoreDataを使いバイナリファイルとして保存する
2.動画自体はDocumentファイルに保存し、CoreDataに動画のファイルパスだけを保存する。

1と２でパフォーマンスに違いは出たりするものでしょうか？
または全く見当違いで、動画を保存する際は他にベストプラクティスがあったりするものでしょうか？

アドバイスいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 「カメラ機能を使いフォトライブラリに動画を保存するところまではたどり着いた」のであれば、「アプリ内に動画を保存」するのはもっと簡単なのですが、どういったところで詰まっているのでしょう?具体的なコードと困難を感じている点を明示していただければ、解決策を得やすいだろうと思います。「下記２つの方法が考えられるか」＞保存した動画のカタログ情報を保持するのにCore Dataを使うのは一つの有力な手段ではありますが、必須ではありません。また、Core Dataは動画のような膨大なバイナリーデータを複数保存するのには向いていませんので「１.」の方法は避けた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実機のDocumentの中身を確認すると動画データが保存できていました。動作は確認できていたものの、コードを理解できていなかったため、フォトライブラリのディレクトリにのみデータが保存されていると勘違いしていました。失礼いたしました。コメント頂いた通り、「１.」の方法は避けて「２.」の方法で進めてみます。